# Пока что (,) да

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

В голову пришла незамысловатая фраза, способная служить ответом в повседневной жизни. Но что, если возникла необходимость так ответить в письменной форме?

В качестве своих *примеров* могу привести такие:
**"Пока что нет"**, **"пока что, нет"** или, пожалуй, лучший вариант, на мой взгляд, а именно **"пока что — нет"**.

Склоняюсь к первому или третьему варианту, однако хотелось бы узнать мнение более квалифицированных участников жизни сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. НЕТ и ДА могут быть **отрицательными или утвердительными словами,** и тогда они должны **обособляться**. В то же время ДА может быть союзом или частицей, а НЕТ — сказуемым (тогда обособления нет).
2. **ПОКА и ПОКА ЧТО** — это наречия. Из словаря:  ПОКА. I. нареч. В течение некоторого времени; до сих пор ещё; впредь до чего-л. Побудь п. здесь. ПОКА ЧТО, нареч. В настоящее время, независимо от того, что произойдёт потом. Я пока что доволен.
3. Эти наречия могут присоединяться к утвердительным и отрицательным словам, образуя **единую конструкцию**,  а могут **обособляться** от них интонационным тире — это авторское решение, зависящее от структуры  предложения.

Примеры:

**1. Нет обособления:**

Ты это купил? — спросила Орли. — **Пока что нет**, — усмехнулся Глеб .

Страшно? **Пока что нет**. Пока что даже как-то приятно.

**Пока что нет**, не договоримся, ― вздохнул Кудинкин и честно раскрыл карты.

**2. Обособление с помощью тире:**

― Начальник сыскной полиции? ― Пока что ― да. Присаживайтесь.

Ты довольно часто спрашивала ― уж не им***т  ли я? Увы, **пока что ― нет.**  [Сергей Довлатов (1985)]

**3. Слово НЕТ в функции сказуемого** не обособляется:

К сожалению, такой убедительной модели у нас **пока что нет**. **Пока что нет** подходящего слова в русском языке. **Пока что нет** никаких перспектив.

Comment: Тире (или многоточие) возможно как по интонационным причинам, так и по факту сокращения высказывания. Вариант же с _запятой_ для меня выглядит "авторским" волюнтаризмом, поскольку обособлению подвергается обстоятельство времени - это не менее противоестественно, чем "сейчас, нет".

Comment: Ладно, согласна, уберем "волюнтаризм".